# Laravel broadcast notification to all friends

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, pusher, laravel-echo

I am trying to implement notifications feature on my website. Here is my code ( hope my approach is correct)

-create a channel called notification.{userId} (userId is authenticated user id)
-when I comment to his post for example, trigger **NewComment** event that broadcasts on **notifications.{$notification->user_id}**

here is my code :

```
public function newComment($post, $user){
    $notification = new Notification; // this is notification model for my database table
    $notification->type = 'new-comment';
    $notification->notified_by = $user->id;
    $notification->user_id = $post->owner->id;
    $notification->save();

    event(new NewNotification($notification));
}
```

**NewNotification.php** event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Notification;
use App\Transformers\NotificationTransformer;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewNotification
{
    protected $notification;

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Notification $notification)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('notification.' . $this->notification->user_id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith(){
        return fractal()->item($this->notification, new NotificationTransformer());
    }
}
```

**Broadcast channel route:**

```
Broadcast::channel('notification.{userId}', function($user, $userId){
      //comparing ($userId == $user->id) always turns true 
});
```

*Subscribing to presence channel on client side (using Vue)*:

```
Echo.join('notification.' + this.user_id) //user_id is logged in user id
              .listen('NewNotification', function(response){
                console.log(response);
              });
```

For some reason event is never called. I do not know if i should change logic in broadcast channel route. Should i pass notification id and check if notification->user_id === $user->id . I have tested this way but still not response in console.

Comment: What's your queue driver set as?

Comment: @btl, it is database. I think i forgot to run queue worker in terminal. Also im not sure, if i use private channel, does event triggers in channel if channel is occupied(has only 1 user) since user will listen only to his channel?

Comment: Yeah make sure the worker is running. I think a user needs to be actively listening for the event to route through, not 100% sure though. Are you using [laravel echo server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)? Or just a websocket by itself?

Comment: Im using laravel echo server

Comment: Ok cool. Your channels look correct. Does the web inspector show the ws connection is working?

Comment: I use redis for the queue and Laravel Horizon to manage the workers. It's a nice setup and makes debugging much easier.

Comment: @btl I got expected results after runing queue. Sometimes i forget i do not have automated jobs in local server xD. I am planning to implement Beanstalk in the future.

Comment: Cool, glad it's working. You should setup supervisor or pm2 and have them run on startup. I forget about starting the queue too so those are nice to handle it auto matically.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone finds this answer helpful :

In order to fire an event, event class should implement **ShouldBroadcast** class.

So

```
class NewNotification{
   //code here
}
```

becomes

```
class NewNotification implements ShouldBroadcast{
   // code here
}
```

*Do not forget to run queue:listen if you have not set up automated jobs*